# Forward Outlook Email by Filtering using Macro Rule

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2010, regex

Can you guys help me to fix the script below. What i need is if the email body contains < it will forward to my personal email. I am using Outlook 2010. Here is a sample email text:

"That was fast! It only took < 60 seconds to reboot the modem."

If there is a space between < and 60, it will forwarded to my email but if there are no space, it won't.

```
Public Sub FWItem(Item As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim Email As Outlook.mailitem
    Dim Matches As Variant
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Pattern As String

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then

        Pattern = "(\s[<]\s)"
        With RegExp
            .Global = False
            .Pattern = Pattern
            .IgnoreCase = True
             Set Matches = .Execute(Item.Body)
        End With

        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Item.subject ' Print on Immediate Window
            Set Email = Item.Forward
                Email.subject = Item.subject
                Email.Recipients.Add "alias@domain.com"
                Email.Save
                Email.Send

        End If
    End If

    Set RegExp = Nothing
    Set Matches = Nothing
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the pattern that i used to filter the email body:

```
Pattern = "(\s[<]\s)"
```

But it did not work.

Comment: "contains <" - if you only look for that one character, then your pattern should just be `"<"`.

Comment: What is the question? I mean you've shared some code but not explained which part does/doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. I am assuming the issue is with the regex, and not that the email isn't being sent (or any other reason).

I think your pattern needs to simply be

```
(< )
```

So in your code you would use

```
Pattern = "(< )"
```

This will match the < and a white space immediatly after. As such

`<60` does not match
`< 60` does match
`< 60` does match
`<60` does not match
`< Hello` does match

I point out the last one as to me that may be an issue if some one uses the quote marks for other reasons... < End Of Message >